# PHP 5.5 shows internal server instead of displaying errors

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have updated my PHP version 5.3 to 5.5 and currently it starts to display internal server error instead of showing errors.

My php.ini settings configurations are as below:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

I have already trial-and-error'ed various options available at stack overflow:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
error_reporting = E_NOTICE
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: I have checked it for development and production mode both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php and fnc, I have used in two ways as given below, both of them work fine at my end.

Option 1: Add the following line at the end of php.ini file or change value if it is existed as:

```
display_errors = On
```

Option 2: Change settings run time, add below line at the top of PHP script file.

```
<?php

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set display_errors to On in your php.ini. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors.

Comment: following lines are mentioned in php.ini file ; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off I have to uncomment anyone or have to add this manually.

Comment: If they're in there, you can just uncomment them.

Comment: un comment is not wrking. xampp thrown error to start.

Comment: Please paste your php.ini

Comment: Please tell which piece of php.ini code  you need. as stackoverflow has limited character to ost.

Comment: actually i tried to post php.ini files here but it shows 3000 character only allowed

Comment: Come on, take the parts that you changed and post them somewhere. I'm sure you'll find a way to share that. Or just go comment out the lines that you uncommented before, and go line-by-line to identify what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks fnj for providing hint. I have find two solutions.